# Append to Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to append to two different arrays based on the value of a variable.

```
$availableDates = array();
$unavailableDates = array();

$total1 = 100 //For example

foreach($selectedDates as $checkingDate)
    {
        $checkQuery = some query                    
        $total2 = number of rows from $checkQuery

        $availableSeats = $total1 - $total2;

        if($availableSeats > 0)
                {
                    $availableDates[] =  $checkingDate;
                }

        else
                {
                    $unavailableDates[] = $checkingDate;
                }       
    }
```

`$selectedDates` is an array of dates - e.g. `array(2014-01-01, 2014-01-02)`.

Problem now is, it appends to `$availableDates[]` perfectly, but it does not append to `$unavailableDates[]` even when the condition is satisfied. What am I missing?

Comment: Post actual code. You have edited out the problem.

Comment: please dump the variables...

Comment: Try array_push(): array_push($unavailableDates, $checkingDate);//But I don't see why your code wouldn't work as written

Comment: might be your variable $unavailableDates is reset after, loop where you have print your variable values , because there is no problem in your code

Comment: echo in both loop...and paste your full program..with hard coded values..might missing something...There is NO ERROR in this code.

Comment: How yoy know `Else` is executing ... Why not `Echo "Else part"` in the else condition to check whether it is being executed or not?